# Telerik Report omitting data

Tags: telerik, reporting, telerik-reporting

After performing a product evaluation by one of the managers other can change the scoring for certain categories. This changes in scoring are stored in the database for reference.

The structure of the evaluation is like this:
 Evaluatoin
  - Category
      - Scoring point

an evaluation can have many categories which all can have many scoring points.

My problem is the following:

If I change a scoring point a few times all is entered in the database but in the reports i am only seeing the first scoring point. The rest of them with the same name are left blank but are using space just as it would if all were visible. The stored procedure that is delivering the data is working fine. It bring all data to the report which then displayes it wrong.

`=Fields.CategoryName` is working fine... every category name is displayed correctly
`=Fields.ScoringPointName` is not working... it displayes only the first and leavese all the rest blank... if for example a scoring point name is Product robustnes it would display only the first change of scoring but wouldnt display the rest

Any ideas???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out what the problem was. Maybe it will be helpful for other people

I was showing the data in a group header section with grouping =Fields.DefinitionText. Thus it will only repeat if the Fields.DefinitionText is distinct. About the empty space it's caused by the detail section that repeats for every data record. Thus if I want to display all of the data records I have to move the group header section textboxes to the report's detail section.

[Here](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/designing-reports-understanding-report-sections.html) and [Here](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/data-items-grouping-data.html) are some usefull things about reporting.

Cheers